# Flutter The method '[]' was called on null error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app with Firebase backend. I am using email and google sign in method. When user sign in for the first time using google sign in method, this wierd error pops up just for a second. (When user register using email/pswrd, this doesnt appear)

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState>#e1ffb):
>   **The method '[]' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling:**

Here is my code on github: https://github.com/TenPetr/fridgy
(this error is probably caused from **lib/pages/home.dart** file)

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This error appear when you call an element in a empty list, check your list in Stream Builder

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you Stream is in its loading state, the way to solve this is to use the ConnectionState of the stream and show either a ProgressBar or a empty container.

```
//Data Logic
Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot =  Firestore.instance.collection("collection_name").snapshots();

//Ui Logic
StreamBuilder(
  stream: snapshot,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      //Further Logic
      return Text('It works');
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Went over your codebase, it seems that the [firebaseAuth User](https://github.com/TenPetr/fridgy/blob/c85b90cf5261027a2d68ab7e4afe310fc04ea30b/lib/main.dart#L18) Stream is taking a bit of time to load. <br/> What you can do now is either wait for that stream to complete or set the initialData prop of the StreamProvider. <br/> `StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
    value: AuthService().isLogged,
    initialData: TempUser,
    child: child
  );`

Comment: Well, yes, you are probably right, but I have figure it out. Instead of method checking if document with current users id exists, I used authResult property result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser, wich is boolean. So I can determine if user is logged for the first time or not. Anyway, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error is timing due to the user @Preet Parekh. And I solve this issue by removing method that was responsible for determine if user is logged for the first time or not. Instead of this, I used propery on AuthResult - `result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo

Thanks for your help.